# In a multiple-nsf xpages project, should I set each nsf database as a separate repository?

Tags: github, xpages

I am setting up github for my xpages projects, and one of them has multiple nsf databases linked to it. What is the best practice? Do I set up one repository per database, or make one big project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would make one repository with each db of the application being a project within that repository. This would reduce the hassle of branching and merging because when you create a new branch you would have all of the applications within that branch.

Comment: I second that. Just have multiple projects in one repository

Comment: I do 1 repository per database as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using submodules as well. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules or https://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2009/11/nested-git-repositories-with-github-using-submodule-in-three-minutes/ for reference.